# Where can I add a method call when the MainWindow is completely built in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mainwindow

I need to call a method the first thing after the MainWindow is built. I've added this code to the XAML:

```
Loaded="MainWindow_Loaded"
```

And this method to MainWindow:

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SelectScenario dlg = new SelectScenario();
    dlg.Top = 22;
    dlg.ShowDialog();
    if (ScenarioSelected == true)
    {
        LoadScenarioFile(SelectedScenario);
    }
}
```

But the SelectScenario dialog box is being called *before* the MainWindow is fully built. Where can I insert the method call for the SelectScenario dialog box so I know the MainWindow has been completely built?

Comment: You might need to wait for all contents to have loaded

Comment: Okay, how can I check to know all contents have been loaded?

Comment: Well, i don't know. I think relying on the state of this UI in this way is not a good idea. I would try to get around having to do this in the first place.

Comment: Well, this is basically a splash screen and it fits into a section of main window. I just need to know that the main window is built and then call this dialog box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an event called "ContentRendered" you could try this instead of loaded.

Comment: Glad I could help :)